# UnityContainer Performance test results

Tags: c#, performance, unity-container, console-application

As part of a basic presentation on unity i have created the following console application (kinda lengthy):

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ISimpleClass, SimpleClass>();
        container.RegisterType<ISingletonWithUnity, SingletonWithUnity>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        double N = 10000;
        double sum = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Testing performace of a basic new object");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            ISimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass();
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            sum += (end - start).Milliseconds;
        }
        double average = sum/N;
        Console.WriteLine("Average time for basic new object is: " + average);


        Console.WriteLine("Testing performance of transient resolve using unity");
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            ISimpleClass simpleClass = container.Resolve<SimpleClass>();
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            sum += (end - start).Milliseconds;
        }
        average = sum / N;

        Console.WriteLine("Average time for transient resolve using unity is: " + average);


        Console.WriteLine("Testing performance of basic singleton");
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            BasicSingltonClass basicSingltonClass = BasicSingltonClass.Instance;
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            sum += (end - start).Milliseconds;
        }
        average = sum / N;

        Console.WriteLine("Average time for basic singleton is: " + average);

        Console.WriteLine("Testing performance of unity singleton");
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            SingletonWithUnity singletonWithUnity = container.Resolve<SingletonWithUnity>();
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            sum += (end - start).Milliseconds;
        }
        average = sum / N;

        Console.WriteLine("Average time for unity singleton is: " + average);
```

The classes used in the test are pretty straight forward:

- SimpleClass is just an empty class
- BasicSingletonClass is exactly what it is using the usual Double Checked Locking on the instance getter.
- SingletonWithUnity is also just an empty class but as you can see it is registered with the ContainerControlleredLifetimeManager.

The results i'm getting as N goes higher (up to 1 million) are showing that using unity is actually much slower then not using it. I used to think that Unity had some sort of caching of resolves and such to make it much more faster, especially in transient resolve.

Here's an example of a result of running the performance test application when N is set to 10,000:

> Testing performace of a basic new object
>   Average time for basic new object is: 0.0007
>
> Testing performance of transient resolve using unity
>   Average time for transient resolve using unity is: 0.008
>
> Testing performance of basic singleton
>   Average time for basic singleton is: 0.0012
>
> Testing performance of unity singleton
>   Average time for unity singleton is: 0.0033
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

As you can see using Unity is a performance impact.
I would like to get your honest opinions on whats going on behind the scenes to explain these results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that Unity must locate the appropriate concrete class for the interface, and *then* if its found, construct it. Even cacheing the resolve doesn't change the fact that there's an extra method call and (possibly cached) look-up over just newing up the object yourself.

Unity isn't really intended to increase object creation performance. It's intended to provide a robust DI container that can help reduce coupling and ease testing of your code.

Comment: I did not think that it was intended to increase object creation. But i was very surprised by the magnitude of these results, hence i'm looking for an explanation as to why these results are happening

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I can't answer about the specific magnitude differences (though I think the extra level of indirection is responsible.) You might want to try using Stopwatch rather than differences in DateTime.Now, since the resolution will be much higher.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's interesting to give a theoretical explanation, but in practice this will never be a problem. I can hardly imagine that resolving your classes is the bottleneck in your program.
You should only improve performance when it's necessary, not beforehand!

Comment: Unity resolution is causing a 9s bottleneck in our app from 36 calls to resolve. I assume the person is asking as he has a similar problem and is trying to work out what to do with it. Like me.